How to fix this outlet stub up through concrete?
How could we fix this situation?

So a contractor laid a 2" conduit for electrical underneath and stubbed it up. This location is supposed to be for an in-floor plug. When another contractor came and poured the concrete, they didn't box out the stub-up, so now it's just a 2" conduit sticking out of the 4" concrete slab.
Our electrician said he would have preferred 3/4" conduit in the first place and for the box to have been set before the pour, and is trying to figure out a way to fix it within code compliance for the 2017 NEC.
Cutting the concrete is not an issue as the concrete contractor offered to come cut the hole with a concrete saw at no cost. The question is how to go from this 2" conduit to an in-floor outlet box.
Does anyone know of an outlet box that has bottom knock-outs, or another way that we might want to go about fixing this?

Have the concrete contractor cut a hole big enough so the 2 inch can be reduced to 3/4 to mate with the floor box. Then have the hole filled with concrete again.  I'm not sure the code allows abs plastic as conduit for electric cable. Maybe you can have 3/4 NM flex conduit run through the 2".

@RMDman  From what I read on here conduit must be electrically rated.  Cannot use plumbing pipes, even if they look/feel the same.

The 2" conduit has already passed an electrical inspection, if that helps. There will be another inspection later, however.

Passing inspection is very good.  Conduit must be a certain minimum size for the amount of wires/cables in it.  Bigger is good.  @RMDman's comment should be good for fixing it, or an answer.

@crip659, The ABS plastic is the unknown for me.  It would not pass for a shield of electric cable, in my location. It may where the OP is located.

Why does the electrician not want 2"  is their hole saw blunt or something?

@Jasen possibly because the box the electrician wants to use has a 3/4" knockout, not a 2" knockout.

I checked the conduit, it says "Atkore | Heritage Plastics | Allied Tube & Conduit | QCP 2" SCH40 Rigid PVC Conduit - Aboveground and Underground - Max 90C Wire - Sunlight Resistant - Intertek"

@Huelsman, I was assuming that, which is why I mentioned the hole saw,   making new holes in boxes is specifically allowed by code.  I would expect an electrician to be aware of that, and to have the necessary tools.

They will have to knock a hole in the concrete big enough for the electrician to insert his box and then mud around it. Tell the electrician to get a PVC adapter if he needs a smaller pipe. He should also supply the box, and it's up to him to figure out how to insert the conduit into the box. Other than that, I wouldn't worry about passing an inspection; the inspector probably won't look into it that deeply anyway.
P.S. It's the electrician's job to develop solutions and help you do your job easier. He should have devised a plan with you that would be code-compliant and pass an inspection. If he isn't doing that, you need new electricians.

2" should not be a problem. Making new holes in boxes is specifically allowed by code. I would expect an electrician to be aware of that, and to have the necessary tools.
Cutting holes in concrete is also electrician work,  but this was not expected to be his task for this box, so you (or the concrete cointractor can help him out here by excavating a space to install the box.  Diamond saw, core drill, rotary impact drill, whatever it takes.
